# issue with JSON parsing in ruby

Tags: ruby, json, httparty

```
page = HTTParty.get("https://api.4chan.org/b/0.json").body
threads = JSON.parse(page)
count = 0

unless threads.nil?
    threads['threads'].each do
      count = count + 1
    end
end


if count > 0
    say "You have #{count} new threads."
     unless threads['posts'].nil?
      threads['posts'].each do |x|
        say x['com']
      end
     end
end

if count == 0
    say "You have no new threads."
end
```

for some reason it says that posts is empty i guess but threads never is....I am not sure whats wrong and its doing the same thing for me on the facebook plugin but that worked yesterday and now nothing. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your `threads` variable like this:

`threads = JSON.parse(page)['threads']`

The root node in the JSON response you received is "threads". All of the content you want to access is contained within the array of this node.

Each `thread` contains many `posts`. So to iterate through all of the posts, you will need to do something like this:

```
threads.each do |thread|
  thread["posts"].each do |post|
    puts post["com"]
  end
end
```

Overall I would rewrite your code like so:

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

page = HTTParty.get("https://api.4chan.org/b/0.json").body
threads = JSON.parse(page)["threads"]
count = threads.count

if count > 0
  puts "You have #{count} new threads."
  threads.each do |thread|
    unless thread["posts"].nil?
      thread["posts"].each do |post|
        puts post["com"]
      end
    end
  end
else
  puts "You have no new threads."
end
```